# Apache NiFi Docker Image - Mounting Content Repository as bind mount

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-nifi

I've been working with **NiFi** docker image, for what I've seen examples that mounts several different volumes as follows (`docker-compose` example):

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:1.9.2
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "9991:9991"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: nifi-data-conf
        target: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
      - type: volume
        source: nifi-data-database_repository
        target: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/database_repository
      - type: volume
        source: nifi-data-flowfile_repository
        target: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/flowfile_repository
      - type: bind
        source: /mnt/data/nifi/nifi-data-content_repository
        target: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository
      - type: volume
        source: nifi-data-provenance_repository
        target: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/provenance_repository
      - type: volume
        source: nifi-data-state
        target: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/state
```

However this presents a problem: volumes are stored in the host filesystem in `/var/lib/docker/volumes` path, and I have a really small partition.

So I wanted to move it to another partition. To avoid some NiFi starting problems on startup (just suffered them), I keep all the other volumes setup as in the previous example, and only the one volume that stores the flowfiles content which is the one that really increases its size as you can see here in my case, will be mounted as a `bind mount`:

```
VOLUME NAME                                                        LINKS               SIZE
centos_nifi-data-content_repository                                1                   11.21GB
```

So I modified the previous setup for:

```
      - type: bind
        source: /mnt/data/nifi/nifi-data-content_repository
        target: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository
```

Where my `/mnt/data` path is another partition with way more space available.

But then, I got some problems again when starting NiFi container. I didn't expect to get it because it should be a kind of empty folder, since before starting NiFi for the first time I don't expect to be anything there...

Please allow me to insert here the logs as a pastebin link, since they were way too long:

https://pastebin.com/Uf9m2Fsu

I've been googling around it for a while but found nothing useful for it. Any clue about the matter?

Thanks in advance